Flutter on Android: KeyboardListener and Text Input Fields
We are not flutter programmers, however we have a outsourced team that develops an app for us. Unfortunately they are unable to solve the issue hence why we are putting it out to the wider community.
Here is a bit of background:
We have a screen in our app that is supposed to accept input from an external barcode scanner and then perform some logic with the scanned barcode. We do not want the on-screen keyboard to display when the user is scanning via the bluetooth scanner so we are using a KeyboardListener to capture the input and then process the data.
The user can tap a button to display a text input field, and the on screen keyboard, to manually enter a barcode if required. This switches the KeyboardListener off and replaces it with the input field. They can tap the button again to swap this back.
Here is the issue:
When the app is cold booted, if the user navigates through the app to aformentioned screen without tapping on any input fields, the bluetooth scanner works and no on-screen keyboard is displayed.
HOWEVER, if at any time after the app is opened a user taps into an input field, in any screen, then proceeds to the scanning screen and scans using the bluetooth scanner, the on-screen keyboard displays to the user even though there is no input field with focus. If we add code to suppress the on-screen keyboard after each character is received from the scanner, they on-screen keyboard flashes up and down for each keystroke.
I don't really know how the programmers are dealing with state etc in the app, we have a feeling thatwidgets aren't destroyed when new pages are opened and when pages are closed... Not sure if this could be related.
We have tried everything we can find online to no avail.
We have also looked at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/51478 in depth which flutter says they've fixed the issue, but we are running the latest stable version of flutter 3.19.6 and it is still an issue.
Below is the widget code, hoping that someone more experienced will be able to see something obvious that we are all missing. FYI, we replaced the onKeyEvent with very basic logic to log the keys being pressed (ie took the controller out of the equation) and the issue was still present.
We also noticed that "sometimes" when you switch to another app and then return to our app, the issue is rectified until you tap in another input field... Not all the time, but sometimes??
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: AppColors.primaryColor,
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                horizontal: size.width(15.0), vertical: size.height(5.0))
            .copyWith(
                bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom +
                    size.height(5.0)),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              flex: 4,
              child: SizedBox(
                height: 40,
                child: controller.isKeyboardOpen == false
                    ? KeyboardListener(
                    focusNode: _focusNode,
                    autofocus: true,
                    onKeyEvent: (KeyEvent event) {
                      if (event is KeyDownEvent) {

                        if (event.logicalKey == LogicalKeyboardKey.enter) {
                          SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod('TextInput.hide');
                          controller.update();
                          controller.pickScanFunctionality(pickableLines);
                        } else {
                          controller.qtyScanningController.text += event.character ?? "";
                          print(event.character.toString() + " received");
                        }
                      }
                    } ,
                  child: SizedBox()
              )

                :
                    appTextField(
                      textEditingController: controller.qtyScanningController,
                      hintText: "Scan...",
                      enableInteractiveSelection: false,
                      focusNode: controller.pickScanFocusNode,
                      inputType: controller.isKeyboardOpen
                          ? TextInputType.text
                          : TextInputType.none,
                      autoFocus: true,
                      onFieldSubmit: (value) {
                        controller.pickScanFunctionality(pickableLines);
                      },
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        return;
                      },
                      suffixIcon: GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          controller.qtyScanningController.clear();
                        },
                        child: const Icon(
                          Icons.close,
                          color: AppColors.lightBlueColor,
                          size: 20,
                        ),
                      ),
                      isReadOnly: false,//!controller.isKeyboardOpen,
                      showCursor: true,
                      hintTextStyle: const TextStyle(
                        color: AppColors.lightBlueColor,
                        fontSize: 14,
                      )),
              ),
            ),
            size.widthSpace(10),
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                Get.to(const BarcodeScanScreen());
                Get.find<BarcodeScannerController>().isPickScanningBarcode =
                    true;
                Get.find<BarcodeScannerController>().update();
              },
              child: Icon(
                MdiIcons.barcode,
                color: AppColors.whiteColor,
                size: 40,
              ),
            ),
            size.widthSpace(15),
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                controller.isKeyboardOpen = !controller.isKeyboardOpen;
                printData("isKeyBoard:: ${controller.isKeyboardOpen}");
                controller.update();
              },
              child: const Icon(
                Icons.keyboard_alt_outlined,
                color: AppColors.whiteColor,
                size: 30,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


Use a Bluetooth barcode scanner that support SPP or BLE mode. Your app receives barcodes in a way other than keyboard input. Therefore there's no such issue you mentioned. Extra routine for handling scanner connection is required though.
